# Maximum Magnitude Deviation between DFT and DTFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-analysis

This is a cross-post from [signal processing forum](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/52272/maximum-magnitude-deviation-between-dft-and-dtft) as it was not conclusive. 
Let $x[n]$ be a finite-length sequence with length $N$. The continuous DTFT $X(\omega)$ is then
$$
X(\omega) = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j \omega n}.
$$

The length-$N$ DFT of $x[n]$ is
$$
X[k] = \sum_{n = 0}^{N-1} x[n] e^{-j 2 \pi \frac{k n}{N}}.
$$
For this, the DFT is a sampled version of the DTFT, i.e., 
$$
X[k] = X(2\pi k / N).
$$
Please also see posts [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17814/why-does-the-dft-assume-the-transformed-signal-is-periodic) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37967/basics-of-leakage-phenomena-in-dft-and-its-approximation-with-sinc-function/37971#37971). Now, we consider the maximum magnitudes $m_{\textrm{d}} = \max_k |X[k]|$ and $m_{\textrm{c}} = \max_\omega |X(\omega)|$. Because of above, we have $m_{\textrm{d}} \leq m_{\textrm{c}}$.

*How much does $m_{\textrm{d}}$  underestimate $m_{\textrm{c}}$? Is there $\gamma > 1$ such that $\gamma m_{\textrm{d}} \geq m_{\textrm{c}}$?*

Comment: WLOG scale so that the norm is 1, and then we have the inequalities $1/\sqrt{N}\le m_d\le m_c \le 1$. So at the least you can take $\gamma=\sqrt{N}$. Since at each of the inequalities we must have $m_c=m_d$, I'm guessing there's a much better bound...

Comment: @DrorSpeiser thanks for the first bound. I also believe that there must be a much better bound as this would be highly impracticable for signal analysis purposes.

Comment: I find this question to be interesting, though the subject matter is not my field of expertise. But I do have two things to report on, both from Montgomery's paper An Exponential Polynomial Formed with the Lagrange Symbol: 1. the Fekete polynomials give a lower bound $\gamma>2\log\log n/\pi$, so there's no uniform constant $\gamma$. 2. as Montgomery writes, Bernstein's inequality give a bound in terms of "a higher sampling rate", i.e. the polynomial evaluated at roots of unity of higher order. He doesn't prove the bound in the paper, but I think it works for all real polynomials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have found a partial answer in the paper:

Gronwall, T. H. (1921). A sequence of polynomials connected with the $n$th roots of unity. Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society, 27(6), 275–279. http://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1921-03411-2

It actually gives a full construction of a polynomial $F(z)$ such that $|F(e^{i2\pi k/N})| \leq 1$, but $\max |F(z)| = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{1}{\sin \frac{2n + 1}{2N}\pi}$.

This makes the upper bound $\gamma$ in the original question to be asymptotically equal to

$$
\frac{2}{\pi}\left( \log N + C + \log \frac{2}{\pi} \right) + o(1),
$$
where $C$ is the Euler's constant, and $o(1)$ tends to zero as $N$ increases indefinitely. There are various follow up questions:

1. $F(z)$ has complex coefficients. What is the bound for real coefficients?
2. How does this bound change if we add zero padding? It will tend to 1, but how quickly?
3. $F(z)$ gives the worst case bound, but how is this bound for random (Gaussian) distributed coefficients?

Comment: Nice! I find it remarkable that, though the question is intended for signal processing purposes, Gronwall was tightening a bound of Landau that was used to study a number theory problem, namely about what are now called Fekete polynomials, that come up while studying class numbers of quadratic fields. (See reference in loc. cit.)